# Accessing Azure Data Lake with R

Tags: r, azure-data-lake

Anyone worked with R for accessing Azure Data Lake (file upload/download from ADLS in R). If so, any code snippet will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For ADLSgen2, you can use the [AzureStor](https://github.com/Azure/AzureStor) package, which is on [CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=AzureStor). Example code from the README:

```r
library(AzureStor)

# authenticate with AAD
token <- AzureRMR::get_azure_token("https://storage.azure.com",
                                   tenant="myaadtenant", app="app_id", password="mypassword"))
ad_endp_tok <- storage_endpoint("https://mystorage.dfs.core.windows.net", token=token)

cont <- storage_container(ad_endp_tok, "myfilesystem")
list_storage_files(cont)
create_storage_dir(cont, "newdir")
storage_download(cont, "/readme.txt", "~/readme.txt")
storage_multiupload(cont, "N:/data/*.*", "newdir")
```

For ADLSgen1, you can use the [AzureSMR](https://github.com/microsoft/AzureSMR) package. However, note that AzureSMR is deprecated and no longer actively maintained.

Comment: Thanks Hong. Where to find these credentials in Azure. tenant="myaadtenant", app="app_id", password="mypassword"

Comment: Hi, do you know how to connect using Blob SAS token and Blob SAS url?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74459488/connecting-to-azure-data-lake-by-r-using-sas-token